# Tapestry 4.1 conversation scope. Possible?

Tags: tapestry, conversation-scope, hivemind

Is it somehow possible to use conversational scope in Tapestry 4.1 and Hivemind?

Right now, if user opens same page in two different Tabs, then they use same model which is Injected by Hivemind. So if he submits some data in first page, then in fact he changes data which were opened(loaded) in second tab.

Also seems that Tapestry components are in session scope. Because you can't use some components on same page in different tab. If you are submiting something you get error like this

`org.apache.tapestry.BindingException: Unable to update OGNL expression '' of #some_page: 
target is null for setProperty(null,.......`

Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without significant hacking of the framework and the framework has moved on; 4.1 is about five years old, and all the development efforts has been on Tapestry 5 (5.3 is a stable release, 5.4 is coming soon).